# insert element at specific position in cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, insert, cell-array

I've the following cell array:

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

How can I insert another string in a specific position? For example I want to put `'1'` string at position 3, in order to obtain:

```
a = {'a', 'b', '1', 'c', 'd'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done the same way as in matrices:

```
a = {a{1:2}, '1', a{3:end}}
```